# What are the dependencies of org.apache.commons.text?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I've installed the `org.apache.commons.text` Java package in order to use its `StringEscapeUtils` methods.  When I compile the program, it fails with a litany of errors citing elements of the package along with the message

```
error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
```

Evidently, `org.apache.commons.text` depends on `org.apache.commons.lang3`?  This surprised me, since neither the [doc page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) nor the [user guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/userguide.html) for `org.apache.commons.text` mention any dependencies.  Is there any way of knowing what I actually need to install to use `StringEscapeUtils` short of tedious trial and error?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.4. Use a build tool, like gradle or Maven, and it will figure out the dependencies. That's how every Java libray is supposed to be downloaded and used nowadays (and for years now).

Comment: The project architecture is fixed, I can't add a new build tool to it.  Is there no other way?

Comment: You can of course download all the dependencies by yourself. I linked to the page listing them.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad - lang3 is the only dependency, and it doesn't seem to have any itself.  Thanks @JBNizet!

Answer (score 3):

Maven will help you figure this out. I'm not a maven expert, so there might be a better way to do this, but I did it this way. Create a subdir somewhere (/tmp/blah for instance). And create pom.xml in that directory that looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then from that directory, ask maven with:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You'll get a ton of output, but at the end, this is all you end up with:

```
[INFO] com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
```

That should be the complete list -- your project requires apache commons text, and that project requires commons lang3.